# Script to move a specific file from one folder to another on Windows 10

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm getting excel files from a company to my computer, they dump it into a folder on my drive. However the application that I am using has a automatic task that gets specific files and uploads then to their application. To be able to upload them, the app needs the files to be in specific folders.

I found a script that gets files and moves them to another folder:

```
@echo off

set X=<days>

set "source=C:\<Source Folder Path>"

set "destination=D:\<Destination Folder Path>"

robocopy "%source%" "%destination%" /mov /minage:%X%

exit /b
```

Here is the link to where I got it from: [How to Automatically Move Files From One Folder to Another on Windows 10](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/automatically-move-files-one-folder-another-windows-10)

I want the script to get a excel file that has "HRProfile" in the name from a folder that has other excel files (with different names) and move it to a different folder.